# How can I clear the .zip queue?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, game-loop

I've made simple "game loop system" based on RxJS, where I request actions from various actors (including user) and merge them with .zip operator.

The result is a turn-based game loop which pauses only for animation and to request user actions.

Due to that system, user can queue multiple actions and the system will store them in a .zip operator. However, I want to clear that "queue" if user decides to change his mind.

I have a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/az5pthng/6/

Imagine user enters sequence a1, a2, a3, a4, then thinks for a second and decides to change sequence to b1, b2, b3, b4. Then thinks again and types c1, c2, c3, c4.

Currently I have this output, showing every keypress is recorded and played:

```
(3) ["A", "B", "a1"]
(3) ["A", "B", "a2"]
1100
(3) ["A", "B", "a3"]
(3) ["A", "B", "a4"]
1723
(3) ["A", "B", "b1"]
(3) ["A", "B", "b2"]
(3) ["A", "B", "b3"]
(3) ["A", "B", "b4"]
(3) ["A", "B", "c1"]
(3) ["A", "B", "c2"]
(3) ["A", "B", "c3"]
(3) ["A", "B", "c4"]
```

But I want this output, indicating that whenever queueTime$ emits a value - queue$ gets 'reset' with new values:

```
(3) ["A", "B", "a1"]
(3) ["A", "B", "a2"]
1100
(3) ["A", "B", "b1"]
(3) ["A", "B", "b2"]
1700
(3) ["A", "B", "c1"]
(3) ["A", "B", "c2"]
(3) ["A", "B", "c3"]
(3) ["A", "B", "c4"]
```

EDIT: Here's a picture what I'm trying to do: [image: scheme]

Two streams - Turn and Q

Turn should request A and B somehow and wait for Q to provide it's value, if there's any. When Q provides value, Turn waits some time and then repeats. Q, however, breaks it's values by time (I guess with help of .window ?) and discards any value that is not sent to Turn if there's new sequence coming in.

Comment: Is this a coding challenge for a job interview?

Comment: @cgTag No way, it's for my roguelike game where I want to implement "smart" rx-powered turns, where I collect all entity actions and then process them at once. 

You may see it as self-imposed coding challenge, because I want to understand Rx and make it bend to my will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! Though I feel it's not RxJS way, but at least it works as I want. If you have better solution - please post, I'm not very happy with having "outside of stream" variables and flags.

My way is to manage queue by myself. And also have a flag whenever I need input - if whole chain is waiting for input it's true, otherwise not. Based on that flag I either place pressed key to queue or send to chain directly.

```
input$.subscribe(({value, interval}) => {
    if (waitingForInput) {
    queue$.next(value);
    waitingForInput = false;
  } else {
    if (interval < DEBOUNCE_TIME) {
        queue.push(value);
    } else {
        queue.length = 0;
        queue.push(value);
    }
  }
});
```

And:

```
// Request action from other entites
const requestAction = (x) => Rx.of(x);
// Request action from player
const requestQueueAction = () => {
    if (queue.length > 0) {
    return Rx.of(queue.shift());
  } else {
    waitingForInput = true;
    return queue$.pipe(op.take(1));
  }
}
```

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/az5pthng/7/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but if you want to postpone the queue to triggered (because the user might change his/he mind, then you can use [debounceTime(1000)](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime) where 1000 in ms.
If you want to clear the queue you can use the same operator with [distinctUntilChanged](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged) to recognise the changes and do what ever you want to do!
Hope that helps

Comment: I don't want to postpone the queue. My problem is that I have queue, which should produce values over other observable and at some point I want to replace the queue with another.

Example: User presses A,B,C,D waits 1.5 seconds, E,F,G. I want A send immediately, then after 1 second B, (after .5 second user presses E), so after 1 second - it should discard C and D and produce E. And the problem is that either have `.forkJoin` or `.switchMap` or whatever - and my queue doesn't store values. Or I have .zip - but then I don't know how to make my queue discard values